# Laravel Aimeos package mandatory product attributes

Tags: laravel, aimeos

How can I mark custom product attribute as mandatory or required?

Did not found any option in admin.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Configurable attributes like you've used can't be mandatory. You can try to use variant attributes instead. You can find the variant attributes in the "Characteristics" subpanel of the product detail view in the admin backend.

Comment: can you please update you answer with instructions where will be the variant attributes & how they will be set for product ?